# Excel Power Query M: passing a header as function parameter?

Tags: excel, parameters, powerquery

In Excel Power Query, in the M language:
How do I pass a column name as a parameter to a function?  As a (contrived) example, supposed I have a table:

```
Fish    Fowl
1   
2       1
        1
2
```

I want a function which will take the table and one of the column-names, and return the sum of that column.  I tried this implementation

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    SumType = (Tbl, ColumnName) =>
         List.Sum(Tbl[ColumnName]),
    FowlSum = SumType(ChType, "Fowl")
in
    FowlSum
```

But it fails with an error: "The column 'ColumnName' wasn't found."

So how can I pass a column name (as a string) to a function, and then access that column within the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Table.Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260736.aspx). In your case the line would look like `List.Sum(Table.Column(Tbl, ColumnName))`.

Comment: Thanks!  Once I looked at the documentation for Table.Column it was clear - even obvious.  But I hadn't realized what that function did.